# Snowflake | does the AWS key (credentials) change for the stage affect the running pipes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So as I need to rotate the AWS S3 Key every 90 days, I was wondering if I alter the STAGE SET CREDENTIALS does affect the running pipes?

Also do you know of any possibility to see all the pipes with the current status?
I know you can see the status of a specific PIPE with SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS('pipename');

Thanks in advance! Cheers, Ovi

I changed the credentials in the test environment and after when I've checked the pipe status I've noticed that I got several errors:
"executionState":"STOPPED_STAGE_DROPPED","pendingFileCount":0

But I am not sure that this is because of the stage change that I did

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to find a solution:

1. I've made a procedure that goes trough all the existing PIPES in a specified DB (input param) and executes the SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS function on all existing pipes in that DB and saves the result into a table:

/*PROCEDURE*/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <DBNAME>.<SCHEMA_NAME>.PIPE_STATUS(DB_NAME STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
   TABLE_NAME   STRING;
   QUERY        STRING;
   OUTPUT       STRING DEFAULT '';
   c1           CURSOR FOR SELECT PIPE_CATALOG || '.' || PIPE_SCHEMA || '.' || PIPE_NAME as PIPE_NAME FROM TABLE(?) 
                ;
BEGIN
   TABLE_NAME := CONCAT(DB_NAME, '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PIPES');
   OPEN c1 USING (TABLE_NAME);

   FOR rec IN c1 DO
       QUERY := 'INSERT INTO <DBNAME>.<SCHEMA_NAME>.PIPE_STATUS (PIPE, SRC) 
       SELECT ''' || rec.PIPE_NAME || ''' , PARSE_JSON(SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS(''' || rec.PIPE_NAME || '''));';               
       OUTPUT := OUTPUT || QUERY;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   END FOR;

   RETURN :OUTPUT;
END;
$$;
```

/*INPUT TABLE*/

```
create or replace TABLE <DBNAME>.<SCHEMA_NAME>.PIPE_STATUS (
    PIPE VARCHAR,
    SRC VARIANT,
    SKEY NUMBER(38,0) autoincrement,
    INSERT_TS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)));
```

/*RESULT QUERY*/

```
SELECT distinct SRC:executionState::VARCHAR AS "executionState" 
FROM <DBNAME>.<SCHEMA_NAME>.PIPE_STATUS 
HAVING "executionState" <> 'RUNNING'
```

If you have any other solution, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.